# double quotient ring isomorphic to polynomials ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question is quite specific, so apologies in advance. I don't have a clue of how to approach this. Answers and links to more general versions of this will also be very welcomed.

Let $F$ be a field and $A = F[x,y,z]$. $J=\langle xy-z^2 \rangle$ is an ideal in $A$. Denote $R=A/J$, and let $I=\langle x+J, y+J \rangle =\langle x+J \rangle + \langle y+J \rangle $ be an ideal in $R$.

I need to prove that $R/I \cong F[w]$.

Comment: What is $w$ supposed to be?

Comment: $w$ is just another element added to $F$, just like $x,y,z$. I assume another letter is used so it won't be confusing

Comment: This isn't true, if $F[w]$ is supposed to denote a polynomial ring.

Comment: I don’t see how this could be true. This is equivalent to taking $F[x,y,z]/K$, where $K$ is generated by $x$, $y$, and $xy-z^2$, which is the same as the ideal generated by $x$, $y$, and $z^2$. But in this quotient, $z+K\neq 0$, since $z\notin K$, but $(z+K)^2 = 0$, But $F[w]$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements. When you say you “need to prove it”, does that mean you were told it was true, or does it mean you really, really, really want it to be true, but don’t know if it is?

Comment: ...or did you just read a $w$ where the original has an $\varepsilon$?

Comment: it's defintely a $w$. I might have a error in the phrasing there, I honestly don't know anymore. so to be exact, $F[w]$ is the mentioned field $F$ with another element added $w$. if I'm not mistaken it means that $F[w]$ is all polynoms with coefficients in $F$ where $w$ is the "variable".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, this question is from a HW, and it's said to be true we just need to prove it.

Comment: If that is what you were told, then it’s incorrect.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That is a trivial implication. The statement incorrect independently of what OP was told. Yes, I'm in a pedantic mood.

Comment: @Servaes: Sigh, fine. “If that is what you were told, then what you were told is incorrect.” (As opposed to what he heard/understood/deduced being incorrect). Happy now? ;-)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Unreasonably deeply satisfied, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

By basic commutative algebra there are canonical isomorphisms
$$(A/\langle xy-z^2\rangle)/\langle x+J,y+J\rangle\cong A/\langle x,y,xy-z^2\rangle=A/\langle x,y,z^2\rangle\cong F[z]/\langle z^2\rangle,$$
where the middle identity comes frome the simple fact that $\langle x,y,xy-z^2\rangle=\langle x,y,z^2\rangle$. It is not hard to prove (exercise for you?) that for any field $F$ you have
$$F[z]/\langle z^2\rangle\not\cong F[w].$$
In particular, what you are asked to prove is *false*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant $I = \langle x + J, z + J\rangle $:

There’s a bijection between $I \subseteq A / J$ and $J \subseteq I’ \subseteq A$ given by $\pi:A \to A / J$, $x \mapsto x + J$, which gives $\pi (I’) = I$.
We can verify that $\pi (xA + zA) = I$, that is

$$I = I’ / J = (xA + zA) / J$$

By the Third Isomorphism Theorem we have

$$R/I = A/J/I = (A/J)/(A/I’) \simeq A /I’ = A/(xA+zA)$$

Finally, we can construct an isomorphism (“cancel out x and z”) and see that 
$$A/(xA+zA) = F[x, y, z] / (xF[x, y, z] + zF[x, y, z]) \simeq F[w]$$

Thus $R/I \simeq F[w]$.

Comment: This is actually a decent guess at what the assigner may have meant...

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The former are delimiters, the latter is a binary operator; they get different spacing assigned by TeX and MathJax.

Comment: Noted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and clear up things before starting. If $\tilde{x}=x+J$, $\tilde{y}=y+J$ and $\tilde{z}=z+J$ as elements of $R=A/J$, then all three elements are nonzero (easy degree considerations); however, $\tilde{z}^2=0+J\in I=\langle\tilde{x},\tilde{y}\rangle$. Hence $I$ is not a prime ideal. Thus the request to prove that $R/I\cong F[w]$ should be interpreted in the sense

> prove that $R/I$ is generated by a single element as an $F$-algebra.

It is not possible that $w$ is an indeterminate over $F$, because $R/I$ is not a domain.

---

Let $A$ be a ring with an ideal $J$. If $R=A/J$ and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, there is a unique ideal $I'$ of $A$ such that $J\subseteq I'$ and $I=I'/J$.

Also, $R/I\cong A/I'$.

What's $I'$ in your case? It is simply $\langle x,y\rangle+J$ (prove it).

Therefore the ring $A/I'$ is generated, as an $F$-algebra, by a single element, namely the image of $z$.